# How does Webdriver / Selenium "talk" to your local web browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

For example with FirefoxDriver, how is it sending out clicks and commands to the firefox instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does this by having a webserver within the Webdriver addon for firefox. The language bindings then do a REST-ish type call to it to get something done, like clicks, typing etc.

You can see the REST-ish interface [Here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). We call it the Json Wire protocol. We also have more native events via the [Advanced User Interactions API](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions). This does more native clicks and typing, at the OS level.

Each language binding takes care of that for you so you dont need to worry about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these links are now dead.